# How to debug xhr onerror?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I've been trying the following javascript in a browser extension but it keeps failing and triggering the onerror() event, but the network monitor shows a server 200 response. How can I find out what is triggering the error?

```
getImage = function (url) {
    return new Promise(function resolver(resolve, reject) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        //Set a generous timeout
        request.timeout = 30000;
        request.onload = function () {
            console.log("loaded");
            resolve(response);
        };
        request.onerror = function(err) {
            console.log("XHR error");
            console.log(err);
            console.log(err.target.status);
            reject(err);
        };
        request.ontimeout = function(err) {
            console.log("timed out");
            reject(err);
        };
        console.log("getting image");
        request.send();
    });
};
```

The error logging just has a status of 0 with statusText of "". What other sources of information are there to track down the issue?

Comment: Look in the Console. It will probably be a same origin policy violation.

Comment: should be dupes on it... Either CORS, not cancelling the action that triggered it, or on file protocol. So what triggers the function? Are you making a call to another domain?

Comment: But the problem is that the console doesn't show anything. Just the error messages I've set up with console.log()